# Excel graph where X and Y values are not in adjacent cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have this particular table and I want to have a plot of PAV vs Freq. But the problem is that since the cells are not laid out in a way that excel can understand (e.g. in a 2 adjacent columns) Excel has no way to know how to link each Y value to it's corresponding X value.

How can I have a graph that has the following points (1000,0.044), (10000,0.396), (100000,3.962), (1000000,43.808)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You copy and paste the desired columns into an adiacent sheet, then you build the desired graph.

Answer (score 0):

1) Highlight the entire table and insert a chart

2) Right-click on the chart and choose "Select Data..."

3) On the left hand side, uncheck all columns *except* the one for `VDD=3V`

4) On the right hand side, uncheck all rows that are *not* `<number>PAV[mV]`

[image]

5) Click "OK", your chart should now look as you want it:

[image]